# How to make custom fb share button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-graph-api

I have a few data items that are displayed in card view of bootstrap table plugin as seen below:

[image: Card View using Bootstrap Table Plugin]

At the bottom of this card, I want to add a custom fb share button that uses information displayed in the card and posts that on Facebook.

So far, I have added the Facebook Javascript SDK at the top of my HTML document and the following code after my closing body tag within a new script tag:

```
$('.btnShare').click(function(){
    elem = $(this);
    postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));

    return false;
});
```

Since the Bootstrap table plugin utilises AJAX to fetch database contents, I am thinking of adding a button field in my database that hold the following record:

```
<a href="myurl"data-title="XYZ" data-desc="Some description for this article" class="btnShare">Share</a>
```

However, even though the share link is displayed, it doesn't open the familiar Facebook share popup, how do I make that open with my custom content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your updating the content of your table dynamically, you need to have delegated event handler, which can be achieved using jQuery's `.on()`.

**JQUERY COODE:**

```
$('<selector of static parent element>').on('click','.btnShare',function(){
  elem = $(this);
  postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));
  return false;
});
```

The target selector has to be the selector of the element which will contain the table content being added dynamically later.

[More info @ Jquery api page...](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: It ends up only refreshing the page. Am I doing something wrong? I have used the static selector to be .button which is the class name for the <th> tag.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked, I found out was it was refreshing.